# Espresso, clicking on a item at position

Tags: android, gridview, android-espresso

I'm trying to click on a item at a specific position in a grid view.

```
onData(instanceOf(MyClass.class))
            .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.my_view))
            .atPosition(R.integer.my_id)
            .perform(click());
```

but I'm getting this `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0`

I'm queuing the responses using MockWebServer, even after the UI is on screen with all the list item, I'm getting this error, I'm not sure why.

Also, I want to get the content of the specific item.

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think that's because you're matching class which is only one, not a specific adapter with values.

Please consider this post:

> The matcher passed as argument to `onData()` must match the value as
>   returned by `Adapter.getItem()`. So the first version doesn't match,
>   because of the wrong type being used. It should be:
>
> ```
> onData(is(instanceOf(IconRowAdapter.IconRow.class)))
> ```
>
> What also can be a pitfall is using equalTo on different kinds of
>   CharSequences. String is a CharSequence, but if IconRow.getText()
>   returns CharSequence instead of String, then this can also be
>   Spannable, Editable, etc in which case equalTo wouldn't match. So if
>   IconRow.getText() return anything but String, make sure to convert it
>   into a String before comparison.

This post was taken from [How to use Espresso to test item in adapter at a specific position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27623800/how-to-use-espresso-to-test-item-in-adapter-at-a-specific-position)

Your question lacks of code of tested class, so I cannot give you direct answer. I can only recommend to read StackOverflow link above.

Hope it help

Comment: hey, I tried that as well, but the error I'm getting is different, whatever I do using "onData" I'm getting indexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: did you noticed that you're usung mocked class, but Espresso as argument has normal one ;-), so your adapter may be empty

Comment: mocked class? 
`onData(is(instanceOf(MyClass.class)))
                .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.my_view))
                .atPosition(R.integer.my_id)
                .perform(click());` this is what I tried, I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to "drill down" a little deeper into the view hierarchy to get to the item in the cell.  Put an additional method call before the ".perform" using the id of the item in the grid cell

```
 onChildView(withId(R.id.???)).perform(click());
```

Use the id of the view that the user would click on.

Comment: hey, the issue was, I did not override the `getItem` call in my adapter